# Align span to top of its container

Tags: css

It seems that when line-height is larger than 1.1 times font-size, the text gets vertically centered in the line. Can it be vertically aligned instead?

In this example

```css
p {
  background-color: pink;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 40px
}

span {
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <span>Hello World</span> Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World
</p>
```

I want the text to butt up against the top of the pink box. All the extra pink space would be below the blue, instead of split above and below each line. The blue box would butt up against the top of the pink. I haven’t found `vertical-align: top` or adding `line-height` to the span to help.

(Edited to show that the text can be very long.)

Comment: Any reason you're using line-height instead of padding or margins?

Comment: Yes, in the actual case, the non-spanned text is several sentences long.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to keep the line-height, you can add `display: inline-block;` to the span
element.

```css
p {
  background-color: pink;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 40px
}

span {
  background-color: lightblue;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <span>Hello World</span> Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World
</p>
```

Comment: This is like what I’m looking for. It just expands the height of the span. Unfortunately, this breaks if the inline-block itself spans a line, which in my case could happen. (Setting the span on each word wouldn’t be practical here.) I wish just setting height:100% on the span worked, but it doesn’t.

Comment: Ooh, I found a way to make this work. In my case, I found a way to avoid letting the inline-block wrap. Thanks, @j-printemps!

Answer (score 5):

Different from Daniel's answer but I guess this meets your requirements too?

```css
p {
  background-color: pink;
  font-size: 20px;
  vertical-align: top;
  height: 40px;
}

span {
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <span>Hello World</span> Hello World
</p>
```

Well, if your text is multiline, I could only think of this solution:

```js
$("#fontsize-input").on("input",() => {
  $("p").css("font-size",$("#fontsize-input").val()+"px");
});
```

```css
p {
  background-color: pink;
  font-size: 25px;
  line-height: 2em;
}

span {
  position: relative;
  top: calc(-0.45em + 1px);
}

.highlight {
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="range" min="10" max="40" id="fontsize-input"/>
<p>
  <span class="highlight">Hello World</span> <span>Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World</span>
</p>
```

Comment: Oops. This won’t work. I should have noted that the non-spanned text could be very long. I have edited the question.

Comment: @JPM what you mean? when it is too long what you want? wrap or overflow?

Comment: It should wrap. Think of the lightblue span as highlighting the first few words of a paragraph.

Comment: @JPM Edited my answer. See if it's what you need :)

Comment: That’s the only thing I’ve thought of too. Unfortunately, it’s fragile. I was hoping for something that didn’t hardcode in that top parameter, something that could automatically accommodate changes in the font-size and line-height. The hardcoding makes the layout less flexible and responsive. . . . But it might be the best I can do.

Answer (score 1):

Solution using padding:

```css
p {
  background-color: pink;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 0 0 20px 0;
  /* padding for top,right,bot,left */
}

span {
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <span>Hello World</span> Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World
</p>
```